# No puedo obtener el estado FINISHED de una AsyncTask en Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Estoy ejecutando un `AsyncTask` de la siguiente forma:

```
MyAsyncUploadFilesTask myAsyncUploadFilesTaskFF = new MyAsyncUploadFilesTask();
Log.e(TAG, myAsyncUploadFilesTaskFF.getStatus().name()); // PENDING

for (Report rp : reports) {
    myAsyncUploadFilesTaskFF.execute(SERVER_URL_TO_UPLOAD_PHOTOS, rp.getFotoFrontal1());
    Log.e(TAG, myAsyncUploadFilesTaskFF.getStatus().name()); // RUNNING
}

Log.e(TAG, myAsyncUploadFilesTaskFF.getStatus().name()); // RUNNING cuando debería ser FINISHED
```

Mi problema es que no logró obtener el estado de `FINISHED`, ¿cómo puedo corregir mi código para poder saber cuando mi `AsyncTask` haya finalizado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asi puedes identificar los estados de tu tarea

```
if(myAsyncUploadFilesTaskFF.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING){

}

if(myAsyncUploadFilesTaskFF.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){

}

if(myAsyncUploadFilesTaskFF.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){

}
```

- PENDING : No ha empezado tu tarea
- RUNNING : `doInBackground` esta ejecutandose
- FINISHED : Termino

Como lo estas imprimiendo ocupa `myAsyncUploadFilesTaskFF.getStatus().toString()`

Me imagino que podrias hacer algo asi (Fuente de la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079645/android-how-to-wait-asynctask-to-finish-in-mainthread) de stack over flow en ingles, pero intente explicar un poco sobre `Handler`)

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case 0:
                //Termino de ejecutar la tarea
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Y dentro del metodo `onPostExecute` (que ya termino)

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
```

Segun la documentación del objeto `Handler`, hay dos utilidades para :

> There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and runnables to be executed as some point in the future; and (2) to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.

Español (perdon si la traduccion no es muy buena) :

> Hay dos usos principales para un Handler (1) Para programar mensajes que seran ejecutadas en algun momento futuro* y (2) Para poner en cola una accion a realizar sobre un Thread diferente al actual

En resumen el uso numero (2) es en tu caso, ya que estas en tu hilo principal, quieres identificar cuando termina de ejecutarse otro hilo diferente al principal (tu tarea asíncrona) y ejecutar una acción (Imprimir algo)

Comment: Yo sé como obtenerlos, a lo que me refiero es que nunca obtengo el último estado de `FINISHED` ...

Comment: @JoriusR actualice!

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de imprimir el estado:

```
Log.e(TAG, myAsyncUploadFilesTaskFF.getStatus().name()); // RUNNING cuando debería ser FINISHED
```

obtén el Status y comparalo con la constante que define que finalizo el `Asynctask`:

```
if(myAsyncUploadFilesTaskFF.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
      Log.e(TAG, "Finalizo!");
}
```

---

Si el estatus no indica que ha finalizado el Asynctask, lo que sucede es que la ejecución del código se realiza secuencialmente pero el proceso del `Asynctask` se realiza asincronamente, por esa razón cuando llega a este punto no dice `FINISHED` porque en realidad no ha terminado.

Comment: Ese es mi problema, bueno, el código que puse fue para obviar un poco todo lo que tengo pero ya hice estas comparaciones, tanto antes, durante y después, respectivamente sigo obteniendo `PENDING`, ``RUNNING`, `RUNNING` nunca entra a dicho log de "Finalizó", :(

Comment: hehe ahora entiendo lo que preguntas, lo que sucede es que la ejecución del código se realiza secuencialmente pero el Asynctask asincronamente, cuando llega a este punto no dice FINISHED porque en realidad no ha terminado. Veo tu código creo que para lo que requieres es una interfaz , voy a agregar info.

Comment: Estaré pendiente, muchas gracias :)